# IComparable Interface

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Temperature : IComparable 
{
    // The temperature value
    protected double temperatureF;

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        Temperature otherTemperature = obj as Temperature;
        if (otherTemperature != null) 
            return this.temperatureF.CompareTo(otherTemperature.temperatureF);
        else
           throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Temperature");
    }

    public double Fahrenheit 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.temperatureF;
        }
        set {
            this.temperatureF = value;
        }
    }

    public double Celsius 
    {
        get 
        {
            return (this.temperatureF - 32) * (5.0/9);
        }
        set 
        {
            this.temperatureF = (value * 9.0/5) + 32;
        }
    }
}

public class CompareTemperatures
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      ArrayList temperatures = new ArrayList();
      // Initialize random number generator.
      Random rnd = new Random();

      // Generate 10 temperatures between 0 and 100 randomly.
      for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
      {
         int degrees = rnd.Next(0, 100);
         Temperature temp = new Temperature();
         temp.Fahrenheit = degrees;
         temperatures.Add(temp);   
      }

      // Sort ArrayList.
      temperatures.Sort();

      foreach (Temperature temp in temperatures)
         Console.WriteLine(temp.Fahrenheit);

   }
}
```

This is an example i have taken from MSDN. In the above example , in the compareTo(
this.TemperatureF.CompareTo(otherTemperature.temperatureF) is used
so how the comparsion is done by sort function() of the arraylist. 
Who provides the other reference object(this) for the comparsion?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. You should generally have at least as much question text as you do sample code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation in which `IComparable` is being used, but in the example of sorting a list, the other references are the other items in the list you're being compared to. Exactly which objects in the list you get compared to will depend on the sort algorithm.

Also, I'd prefer the generic `IComparable<T>` over the plain-old `IComparable`.

Answer (score 1):

"compareTo" is used to compare two objects like this : this.compareTo(anOtherObject)
So, this is the first object, and is anOtherObject the second.
To sort an array, the framework call this method to compare the current object (this) to the next object.

Answer (score 0):

`CompareTo(object other)` will be called by the implementation of the sorting algorithm used. Where in your case the sort algorithm used by `ArrayList.Sort()`.
[Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx)

`other` is an item in the ArrayList.

Check out the [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) section in the article where you got the example

Comment: How does the Sort() function will come to know that the compareTo be used?

Comment: The ArrayList will cast the object to `IComparable`  "If a custom class or structure does not implement IComparable, its members cannot be ordered and the sort operation can throw an InvalidOperationException." [IComparable - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx)